# BadImageFormatExeption in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, clr, static-libraries, wrapper, linker-errors

i was wrapping cimg (native c++ header library) to dot net and i tested it and it works fine in c++ CLR and the mathod i used looks like this.
 since cimg is only a header file i created a win32 static library project and i build it 
 then i used the header in CLR c++ and added my win32 static library in the additional library
 (my reason for this is to escape from linker errors),  and it works fine
and finally i tried to make a DLL from the CLR so that i would be able to use it in my c# GUI project 
 so i changed the output of the CLR c++ project to DLL ,then i referenced it inside c# winform App then when i try to run it i get this error message.

```
    System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024885
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'cpp tester, Version=1.0.4775.2046, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
  Source=WindowsFormsApplication1
  FileName=cpp tester, Version=1.0.4775.2046, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = serak-PC\serak
LOG: DisplayName = cpp tester, Version=1.0.4775.2046, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/serak/Desktop/Cimg Wrapper/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : WindowsFormsApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/serak/Desktop/Cimg Wrapper/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/cpp tester.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

  StackTrace:
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in c:\Users\serak\Desktop\Cimg Wrapper\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Your C# program is running in 64-bit mode.  It cannot load an assembly that contains 32-bit native code.  Either build the C++/CLI assembly to target x64 or force your C# program to run in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be possible that you have a mismatch in the "bitness" of your DLL and your app? If you are doing a 32-bit build, make sure that both the C++/CLI wrapper .DLL and the WinForms C# GUI .EXE are built using platform target **x86** (not "*Any CPU*"). To check that, in VS2010 you can go to project properties and then select the "*Build*" tab.

Comment: @user1250098: You're welcome. If this post answers your question, you may want to mark it as answer accordingly.

Comment: @user1250098: [From the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): "_When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer._"